# startAccessingSecurityScopedResource never returns success

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, appstore-sandbox

I'm developing a sandboxed Mac App Store app which asks the user where to save files it downloads from elsewhere. I have this code to get the folder from the user (stripping out some error checking):

```
NSOpenPanel* openPanel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
[openPanel setAllowsMultipleSelection:NO];
[openPanel setCanChooseDirectories:YES];
[openPanel setResolvesAliases:YES];
NSInteger result = [openPanel runModal];
NSArray* urls = [openPanel URLs];
NSURL* folderURL = [urls objectAtIndex:0];
NSError* error;
NSData* bookmakeData = [folderURL bookmarkDataWithOptions:NSURLBookmarkCreationWithSecurityScope
                           includingResourceValuesForKeys:nil
                                            relativeToURL:nil
                                                    error:&error];
_saveFolderBookmark = bookmakeData;
```

and when it comes time to move a file into this folder, I have this code:

```
BOOL isStale;
NSError* error;
NSURL* saveFolder = [NSURL URLByResolvingBookmarkData:_saveFolderBookmark
                                              options:NSURLBookmarkCreationWithSecurityScope
                                        relativeToURL:nil
                                  bookmarkDataIsStale:&isStale
                                                error:&error];
BOOL success = [saveFolder startAccessingSecurityScopedResource];

// Move the file somewhere else
NSWorkspace* workspace = [NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace];
NSInteger operationTag;
BOOL copied = [workspace performFileOperation:NSWorkspaceMoveOperation
                                       source:[[self getDocumentsFolder] path]
                                  destination:[saveFolder path]
                                        files:[NSArray arrayWithObject:filename]
                                          tag:&operationTag];
[saveFolder stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource];
```

Which is a lot of code to list to say that startAccessingSecurityScopedResource never returns success for me, either immediately after getting the ULR from NSOpenPanel or in a later run, with the bookmark data being saved in NSUserDefaults.

In the entitlements file, amongst other items, I have:

```
<key>com.apple.security.files.bookmarks.app-scope</key>
<true/>
```

Is there anything wrong with this code?

Comment: Are you seeing any console messages?   Also, double check the code-signing to make sure that is configured correctly.

Comment: In your example, it isn't clear where the `urls` array comes from after the open panel is finished.

Comment: I managed to edit out the line getting urls when I removed the error checking. I've put it back again. There are no messages in the console around the line calling startAccessingSecurityScopedResource.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This one is very easy. You're resolving with NSURLBookmarkCreationWithSecurityScope instead of NSURLBookmarkResolutionWithSecurityScope. Just change that line and it should work.

(It may not work during the same session where you create the bookmark, when you already have access to the URL, because you're not supposed to call it in that case. But on later runs it should, of course, because that's the whole point.)

Comment: Very obvious now that it's pointed out. Makes you wonder why there's two different constants. Thanks!

Comment: If you look at the history, it makes sense. The original set of BookmarkCreation and BookmarkResolution flags in 10.6 didn't have any nicely-matched pairs, so they were completely independent sets of bitmask values, and there was no chance of confusion between, e.g., NSURLBookmarkCreationMinimalBookmark and NSURLBookmarkResolutionWithoutUI. But it would be nice if they added some way for the compiler to warn you about this, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 2):

The correct solution has been given above, but I thought I’d add another possibility for those who are having the same symptom (`startAccessingSecurityScopedResource` never returning `YES`). Make sure that you are using the actual URL returned by Powerbox, which can (probably will) be different than the URL of the actual resource you are trying to access. For example, Powerbox will return a URL to a path, which you would use with `startAccessingSecurityScopedResource` to access a specific file underneath that directory.

Comment: This one bit me just today. I was calling `startAccessingSecurityScopedResource` using a folder beneath the one I got the bookmark for. Thanks for this answer.